# Reading excel file android studio Java

Tags: java, apache-poi, filereader

Happy holidays!

Apology if my english does not make sense.

I'm trying to write app, that takes excel file from downloads folder, searches for certain keywords, finds and counts the occurrences. And then it displays keyword and amount of occurrences.

I have been struggling with this problem for 4 weeks, I'm building it to make my work easier, i know very little about programming.

Thanks in advance!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Initialize variable
    Button btSelect;
    TextView tvUri;
    TextView tvPath;
    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> resultLauncher;
    String nimi;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // assign variable
        btSelect = findViewById(R.id.bt_select);
        tvUri = findViewById(R.id.tv_uri);
        tvPath = findViewById(R.id.tv_path);






        // Initialize result launcher
        resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
                new ActivityResultContracts
                        .StartActivityForResult(),
                new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onActivityResult(
                            ActivityResult result)
                    {
                        // Initialize result data
                        Intent data = result.getData();

                        // check condition
                        if (data != null) {
                            // When data is not equal to empty
                            // Get PDf uri
                            Uri sUri = data.getData();
                            // set Uri on text view
                            tvUri.setText(Html.fromHtml(
                                    "<big><b>PDF Uri</b></big><br>"
                                            + sUri));

                            // Get PDF path
                            String sPath = sUri.getPath();
                            // Set path on text view
                            tvPath.setText(Html.fromHtml(
                                    "<big><b>PDF Path</b></big><br>"
                                            + sPath));
                            nimi = String.valueOf(sUri);
                            try {
                                FetchFromFile();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    }
                });


        // Set click listener on button
        btSelect.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        // check condition
                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                                MainActivity.this,
                                Manifest.permission
                                        .READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                                != PackageManager
                                .PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            // When permission is not granted
                            // Result permission
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                                    MainActivity.this,
                                    new String[] {
                                            Manifest.permission
                                                    .READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE },
                                    1);
                        }
                        else {
                            // When permission is granted
                            // Create method
                            selectFile();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    private void selectFile()
    {
        // Initialize intent
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        // set type
        intent.setType("*/*");
        // Launch intent
        resultLauncher.launch(intent);
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(
            int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
            @NonNull int[] grantResults)
    {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(
                requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        // check condition
        if (requestCode == 1 && grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0]
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // When permission is granted
            // Call method
            selectFile();
        }
        else {
            // When permission is denied
            // Display toast
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

So in this function "FetchFromFile()" if i try to TOAST out "CELL" but it does not find the content and it does not even get pass the first "TOAST".

```
    public void FetchFromFile() throws IOException {

        File file = new File(nimi);

        FileInputStream fileInputStream;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Prints this TOAST", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Does not print this TOAST", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);

        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(1);

        XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(1);

    }
}
```

I have already tried i guess all those solution in stackoverflow but it seems that i am still doing something wrong because it is not working.

[Here are the Uri and Path that the app find about selected file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ruuj8.jpg)